# iso-8859-1 and utf8 in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have 2 two strings, and I want to compare it together.

1. `"H&#7895; tr&#7907; ng&#244;n ng&#7919;"` I think this is iso-8859-1 encoding
2. `u'H\u1ed7 tr\u1ee3 ng\xf4n ng\u1eef'`  unicode.

2 strings have same content. I want to compare it. 
How can I convert the first string to same encoding with the second string.?

Comment: are you using python 3 or 2.x

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have HTML entities, simply use the `HTMLParser` module to unescape those:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape("H&#7895; tr&#7907; ng&#244;n ng&#7919;")
u'H\u1ed7 tr\u1ee3 ng\xf4n ng\u1eef'
>>> print h.unescape("H&#7895; tr&#7907; ng&#244;n ng&#7919;")
Hỗ trợ ngôn ngữ
```

These HTML entities use decimal numbers, not hexadecimal. `7895` is `1ed7` in hexadecimal, etc. They encode unicode codepoints, no UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 used. ISO-8859-1, or Latin-1, is not even capable of encoding these specific codepoints (Vietnamese for 'Language Support', according to Google Translate).